# How to add several empty lines without entering insert mode?

Tags: cursor-motions, edit

Sometimes I want to add several empty lines for better visualization. Now I end up clicking `o<Escape>` multiple times. I would love to reduce number of clicks by using something like `7o` instead, to get 7 empty lines without entering insert mode.

Comment: Well, `7o<Esc>` does work to insert 7 empty lines, so...

Comment: @filbranden Nice, didn't know that.

Comment: Won't `o<CR><CR><CR>[..]` work as well? Why use `o<Esc>`?

Comment: Or even `o<Esc>...[..]`. Dot is cool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had these mappings in my dotfiles for years and they are so useful that I forgot that it's not a built-in feature:

```
" Quickly insert an empty new line without entering insert mode {{{
nnoremap <Leader>o o<Esc>0"_D
nnoremap <Leader>O O<Esc>0"_D
```

They are the equivalent of `o` and `O` but without entering insert mode. The deletion to the black hole register is quite useful for some corner cases (`"_D`).

If you don't want to install a mapping you can add just these two lines to your vimrc.

---

Also out of curiosity [here is how vim-unimpaired does it](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired/blob/4afbe5ebf32ad85341b4c02b0e1d8ca96a64c561/plugin/unimpaired.vim#L185-L198):

```
function! BlankUp(count) abort
  put!=repeat(nr2char(10), a:count)
  ']+1
  silent! call repeat#set("\<Plug>unimpairedBlankUp", a:count)
endfunction

function! BlankDown(count) abort
  put =repeat(nr2char(10), a:count)
  '[-1
  silent! call repeat#set("\<Plug>unimpairedBlankDown", a:count)
endfunction

nnoremap <key> :call BlankUp(v:count1)<CR>
nnoremap <key> :call BlankDown(v:count1)<CR>
```

The difference is that my version puts your cursor on the newly created line whereas Pope's version adds the line but leave your cursor on the same place.

Answer (score 4):

If installing a plugin is an option, Tpope's [vim-unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired/blob/master/doc/unimpaired.txt) is a great pick which provides a mapping to insert empty lines:

- `]<space>` to insert a line under the current line
- `[<space>` to insert a line above the current line

Both accept a count, so `42]<space>` will put 42 new lines under the current position.